# If and When — Singular case, multiple cases

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, subordinate-clauses

In technical writing, you often have to choose whether to begin a sentence with "if" or "when".

> **If** / **When** you need to ... , do ...

> **If** / **When** you need to specify a year, use YYYY-MM-DD format.

However, although in most cases both options are fine, there are also cases when I have a feeling that only one of these words sounds good.

> **When** they are used as objects and not subjects, omit relative pronouns *which*, *who*, *whom*, *whose*, and *that*.

Is it correct to say that to make things more clear to myself, I should read "If ..." as "In **case** ...", while "when" as "In **cases** when ...", and use this method to choose between them? Notice the *case vs. cases* case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of thinking about them seems correct.

"If" would be used for cases where it is unclear whether or not something will happen.

"When" would be used for cases where something is going to happen but won't happen in every case.

Compare for example:

"If you need to specify a year use this format"

It is unknown whether you will need to specify a year but if you do have to then use this format.

"When you need to specify a year, use this format"

You will at some point, or multiple times, need to specify a year and when you do you, use this format

In practice the difference can be quite small and you will likely hear people use them somewhat interchangeably

Comment: Thanks. I still cannot understand why the word "If" doesn't play good in the third example; probably I need to ask another question about it ...

Comment: For the third example, it is known by the author that whatever they are talking about will sometimes be used as objects and is instructing you what to do when this happens so it follows from the logic in my answer that "when" is the appropriate option. Let me know if that makes sense